# Param values are undefined during axios file upload along with text upload using FormData

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios, undefined, form-data

I'm building a simple books management application. In a particular page, I need to upload a book's details along with a picture of the book.

I'm using formData and axios to do this. In the same request, sending the optional image as well as the text inputs.
But on reading the text fields from the body in the server side, all of them are undefined.

How can I resolve this issue ?

**addBooksForm.js**

```
import {  useContext, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./addbooksform.css";
import axios from "axios"
import { authContext } from "../../App";

const Addbooks = () => {

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const [authDet, setAuthDet] = useContext(authContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        title: "",
        author: "",
        genreId: 1,
        price: 0,
        picture:null
    });

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = new FormData()
        data.set("title", values.title)
        data.set("author", values.author)
        data.set("genreId", values.genreId)
        data.set("price", values.price)
        data.set("picture", values.picture)
        console.log(values)

        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/books/",data,
        {
            headers:{
            Authorization:`Token ${authDet.accessToken}`
        }
        })


        if (response.status === 200) {
            navigate('/yourbooks');
        } else {
            console.log("Error occurred "+ response)
        }
    };



    const onChange = (e) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };


    const onFileChange = (e) => {
        setValues({...values, [e.target.name] : e.target.files[0] })
    }

return (
    <div className="addbooks">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <input type="text" name="title" required={true} onChange={onChange} value={values.title}/>
        <h3>Author</h3>
        <input type="text" name="author" required={true} onChange={onChange} value={values.author}/>
        <h3>Genre</h3>
        <input type="number" name="genreId" required={true} onChange={onChange} value={values.genreId}/>
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <input type="number" name="price" required={true} onChange={onChange} value={values.price}/>
        <h3>Upload picture</h3>
        <input type="file" name="picture" onChange={onFileChange}/>
        <button>Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

};

export default Addbooks;

I have also tried adding content-type:multipart/form-data in the config

**Server side controller:**

```
const addBooks = (e) => {
    const { title, author, price, genreId } = req.body;
    // further processing
}
```

here, all the fields are undefined

**server.js:**

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please specify Content-Type in header. headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }

Comment: Hi, As I have already mentioned in the question, I have tried that also. still getting the same result.

Comment: for (const value of formData.values()) {
  console.log(value);
}. Did you instpect formData before sending to server?

Comment: yes, I did console.log(...formData), it logged the values that have been set

Comment: In network tab , did you check payload of http request?

Comment: checked the payload, the formData is being properly sent in the network tab

Comment: please try to console full req object in server side. we can come to know where is the issue?.

Comment: Do you use express.js ? Please share server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like express by itself cannot handle formData. As shown in the server.js file, I did not use any middleware other than express parser for handling formData.

The Issue is solved on using a middleware like multer ( for handling files and formData )